# How to rename all media files in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded media files which are having copyright symbol in their names. They were working on my localhost but sadly they are returning to 404 page on the live server.

The number of files I have uploaded are quiet are around 250+.

I am looking for a way or plugin using which I can rename all the files in the uploads folder and also update their respective entries in the database as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good plugin for doing that. Its called [Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/)

Answer (score 0):

**Step : 1 Update in database Media files**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

below plugin replace name with title of image. (If you want to replace name @abc in image name.you have write logic and update title first).

**Step : 2 Rename Media files (Physical image)**

The Media File Renamer is a WordPress plugin that physically renames media files nicely for a cleaner system and for a better SEO.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-file-renamer/ (Please read instruction)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-media/ (Free plugin)

**Note:** @user3619389 answer is incomplete.It just rename database entries.